# httpcontext.current.handler.master returns null after sometime

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, master-pages, httpcontext

I am facing a problem in ASP.NET. I have a dropdownlist in Master Page and I am accessing it in a library outside the UI project using the below code :

```
 Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;

 if (page != null)
 {
     return page.Master.FindControl("MyDdl") as DropDownList;
 }
```

This code works fine normally. But sometimes if I remain inactive for 15 to 20 minutes and then cause a postback (e.g. Click button, change menu etc..) Master property of the page becomes null. i.e. `page.Master` starts returning null. Then I press F5 to refresh the page and it starts working again. I also searched google but did not find any relative answer. Can anyone guide me what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are experiencing session timeout, your session has ended. There are two places where you can configure session.

First inside your web application web.config like this:

```
<configuration> 
  <system.web> 
     <sessionState timeout="30"></sessionState> 
  </system.web> 
</configuration>
```

or second using IIS manager:

Go to tab with main properties for your application, double click "Session state", at the bottom of the tab there is "Time-out (in minutes)". Also there are other options to change session state storage.

There is also option to check session state using code. Please take a look at this article:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/227382/Alert-Session-Time-out-in-ASP-Net

Happy coding!